# .htaccess rewrite isn't working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

As I'm developing a site with Roots & Wordpress, Roots will rewrite `wp-content/themes/themename/assets/etc` to `assets/etc`but it's not working. .htaccess contains this on the bottom:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^assets/css/(.*) /wp-content/themes/retlehs-roots-e3f7365/assets/css/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^assets/js/(.*) /wp-content/themes/retlehs-roots-e3f7365/assets/js/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^assets/img/(.*) /wp-content/themes/retlehs-roots-e3f7365/assets/img/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^plugins/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

It looks fine to me? But it's not working, so is this a problem with my server or the file itself?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Well, when I open the source of the index page, and click the main stylesheet, it will produce a 404 error.

Comment: Yes that's what I expected. Add the `[R=301]` to see what URL it is redirecting to that's causing the 404. The browser address bar will change and you'll see where it's going (if anywhere)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Add `[R=301]` where?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Hope I did it right. This is what css line looks like:`RewriteRule ^assets/css/(.*) /wp-content/themes/retlehs-roots-e3f7365/assets/css/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]`however, clicking main stylesheet link didn't do anything else.

Comment: You have something else going on, maybe earlier rewrite rules or in a higher directory breaking this. Your rule as you have it above works when [tested here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski There's only one higher directory, and its .htaccess only contains `AddDefaultCharset utf-8`. Some error was given, take a look at this http://snag.gy/twik5.jpg

Comment: That's not an error, it's a successful rewrite. The `[L]` thing means it processed the "Last" flag so that subsequent matches would not override the first rewrite.It's supposed to work that way.

Comment: So what's wrong then? @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: Don't know - I can't debug it for you beyond this. Dig in your logs, try removing the RewriteBase.

Comment: removing rewritebase? how? @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: Comment it out. `#RewriteBase /`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the comments it seems you installed WP in a subfolder. If so the RewriteBase should reflect this.

So it should be `RewriteBase /subfolder`. Also you should remove the `/` in front of `/wp-content...`

So all together:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfolder
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^assets/css/(.*) wp-content/themes/retlehs-roots-e3f7365/assets/css/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^assets/js/(.*) wp-content/themes/retlehs-roots-e3f7365/assets/js/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^assets/img/(.*) wp-content/themes/retlehs-roots-e3f7365/assets/img/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^plugins/(.*) wp-content/plugins/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I already moved this site to another server, but I got to try this!

Comment: The question is: did you use the correct RewriteBase this time or is something else breaking stuff..

Comment: Probably not relevant now but for anyone else reading:

did you remember to enable htaccess rewrite (this is what I was missing): 
sudo a2enmod rewrite